# Clear custom filter from Jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, datatable

I have a datatable with custom filter. I want to clear filter after search. My filter function is.

```
    function SearchByDateRange(startDate, endDate) {
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
        function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
            var min = Date.parse(startDate);
            var max = Date.parse(endDate);
            var date = Date.parse(data[6]) || 0;

            if ((isNaN(min) && isNaN(max)) ||
                (isNaN(min) && date <= max) ||
                (min <= date && isNaN(max)) ||
                (min <= date && date <= max)) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    );
}
```

I tried

```
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.pop();

    myTable.search('').columns().search('').draw();
```

But nothing is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a solution, i was not calling Table.draw() after clearing filter. may be this help someone